# Delete folder in Google Cloud Storage using nodejs gcloud api

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-node

I am using `gcloud nodejs api` to access Google Cloud Storage. I can save/delete/exists files individually, but I didn't find a way to delete a folder or even to list the files in a folder using `gcloud nodejs api`.

I have seen people say that the folder hierachy in GCS is not a real tree structure, but just names. So I tried to use wildcard to match the file name string, which did not succeed.

I wonder if there is any way to do it. If not, what tool should I use?

Answer (score 23):

The code to list files in a directory should look something like this:

```
bucket.getFiles({ prefix: 'directoryName/' }, function(err, files) {})
```

And to delete:

```
bucket.deleteFiles({ prefix: 'directoryName/' }, function(err) {})
```

- [getFiles API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles)
- [deleteFiles API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#deleteFiles)

Comment: The links are out of date. Anyway, I couldn't find any reference to the `deleteFiles` function in the docs. I had to look at the source code. Just one addition: without the option `delimiter: '/'` the function deletes all files and subfolders.

Comment: @SamuelMéndez just updated the links in @Stephen's answer. `deleteFiles` does exist thankfully, documentation is [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#deleteFiles). Cheers

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-delete-file#storage_delete_file-nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `gcloud nodejs api`, there are two other ways to do this.

1. Use the `googleapis` package to access the standard JSON API and XML API of gcs. `googleapis` is a lower level API tool which includes interacting with google cloud services. We can create/list/delete files on gcs. Documentation and examples:

   - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/delete
   - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list
2. Use `childe_process` to execute the `gsutil` commmand line tool. This is not a standard way of programatically accessing the google api, but still a viable solution.Wildcard is allowed when issuing the command. Note that is may not work on the google app engine. Here is an example.

Nodejs

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("gsutil rm gs://[bucketname]/[directory ]/*" , function(error,stdout,stderr){});
```

As Stephen suggested, using standard `gcloud` method `bucket.getFiles` and `bucket.deleteFiles` is the most desirable approach. Since gcs don't have the concept of directories, the manipulation of multiple files obviously should be considered as a bucket level operation.

Comment: I tried the solution using gsutil within my Firebase Cloud Function and I get following error:
gsutil: not found

Is there a way to install gsutil on the Google Service ?

Comment: thinking of trying this in a cloud run instance. do you know if the images pre-install gcloud on them?