# Move/rename folder in Google Cloud Storage using nodejs gcloud api

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, google-api-nodejs-client, gcloud-node

I am trying to rename or move a folder in google cloud storage using the gcloud api.

A similar question explains how to delete a folder:
[Delete folder in Google Cloud Storage using nodejs gcloud api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597802/delete-folder-in-google-cloud-storage-using-nodejs-gcloud-api)

But how can one rename a folder? or move to another path?

Comment: You can also use https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/ to do one-time or recurring transfers from one bucket to another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
'use strict'

var async = require('async')
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')()
var bucket = storage.bucket('stephen-has-a-new-bucket')

bucket.renameFolder = function(source, dest, callback) {
  bucket.getFiles({ prefix: source }, function(err, files) {
    if (err) return callback(err)

    async.eachLimit(files, 5, function(file, next) {
      file.move(file.name.replace(source, dest), next)
    }, callback)
  })
}

bucket.renameFolder('photos/cats', 'photos/dogs', console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks, but once the files are moved, they are no long public. Is there a way to maintain the public attribute?

Answer (score 4):

There are no folders. There is simply a collection of objects that all happen to have the same key prefix, for example `photos/animals/cat.png` and `photos/animals/dog.png` both have a common prefix `photos/animals/` and that's what makes them appear to be in the same folder.

You will need to copy (or move) each of the objects to its new key, for example move `photos/animals/cat.png` to `photos/pets/cat.png` and move `photos/animals/dog.png` to `photos/pets/dog.png`.

That said, Google Cloud provides a way to do this from the command line using [gsutil mv](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv).

Comment: How can You move Bucket/A/B/2018-09-23 to Bucket/A/2018-09-23 ? mv doesn't support it

Comment: @Programmer120 the mv command claims to be able to rename subfolders.