# Google Cloud Storage + Nodejs: How to delete a folder and all its content

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Node 10 and the gcs API.

Trying  to delete a folder and all its content, but I can't figure how.

Nothing found about deleting folders in the API documentation.

I tried the following code, that works with single files, but no with an entire folder:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'my-id'
});
const bucket = storage.bucket('photos');

// Attempt to delete a folder and its files:
bucket
    .file('album-1')
    .delete()
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete folder in Google Cloud Storage using nodejs gcloud api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597802/delete-folder-in-google-cloud-storage-using-nodejs-gcloud-api)

Answer (score 6):

That is because Google Cloud Storage does not really have folders (or as they are called "subdirectories"), just files that begin with a prefix.

For example, your folder `album-1` looks like a folder in the Google Cloud Storage web UI, but in reality, it is just a way to represent files that their name begins with `album1/...`, aka `album1/pic1.jpg` and so on.

In order to delete the "folder" `album1`, you actually need to delete  all the files that begin with `album1/...`. You could do that using the following steps:

```
let dirName = 'album-1';
// List all the files under the bucket
let files = await bucket.getFiles();
// Filter only files that belong to "folder" album-1, aka their file.id (name) begins with "album-1/"
let dirFiles = files.filter(f => f.id.includes(dirName + "/"))
// Delete the files
dirFiles.forEach(async file => {
    await file.delete();
})
```

You can read more about subdirectories at the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork

Comment: thank you! Your solution works, but after made some little changes. I'll write the exact solution other post. One more question: If I have hundreds of images in my bucket, is it a good idea iterate all files, or maybe there are some better option to "files.filter"?

Comment: You should use the prefix option in getFiles instead of getting absolutely every file

Answer (score 4):

Solution apported by @Ohad Chaet, with some adjustments:

```
let dirName = 'album-1';

let files = await bucket.getFiles();

let dirFiles = files[0].filter(f => f.id.includes(dirName + '/'));

dirFiles.forEach(async file => {
    await file.delete();
});
```

Comment: Be careful with `includes` as it will delete also files that contain the folder name. If you use it, I suggest you use `f.id.includes(dirName + "/")`.

Comment: For some reason I needed "%2F" instead of "/"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, this solution is deleting files in parallel

```
    async deleteFolder(bucketName: string, folder: string): Promise<void> {
        const storage = new Storage({
            projectId: your project Id
        });
    
        const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
        const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({ prefix: `${folder}/` });
        await Promise.allSettled(files.map(file => file.delete({ ignoreNotFound: true })))
    }
}
```